# Selecting all from table where one column matches values and another is distinct and not null

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to query which returns all columns so long as one column matches the chosen values and and another the other column has distinct values

I'm using Oracle SQL Dev.

So far I have this...

```
SELECT * FROM table_name
WHERE column_name1 = ANY ('value1, value2, value3... value10)
AND DISTINCT column_name2 IS NOT NULL
```

Without the DISTINCT the query runs fine, but when I add the distinct I get a "missing expression" error.

So in the example below (only an example, my tables hold sensitive information so I can't use those examples), I selected the GLASS_ID as my values for column_name1 and INV_ID as column_name2 I want the only the distinct values.

```
VEH_ID   GLASS_ID   OPENING_SEQ  PART_NUM  PREFIX_CD ANT_FLAG  INV_ID
26975     DB00201        1          201       DB        Y        14
26864     DB00375        1          375       DB        N        16
26865     DB00371        1          376       DB        N        16
26866     DB00371        1          378       DB        N        16
38929     DB00408        1          401       DB        N        12
38930     DB00405        1          402       DB        N        13
38931     DB00404        1          403       DB        N        11
38932     DB00404        1          404       DB        N        12
38933     DB00402        1          406       DB        N        12
38990     DB00401        1          408       DB        N        12
38991     DW01015        1         1015       DB        N        12
```

I appreciate any help.

Comment: You're missing `FROM` keyword; besides, what do you want to achieve with `DISTINCT column_name2 IS NOT NULL` ? `DISTINCT` is used to get non duplicate values, so it does not make much sense using it in a `WHERE` condition

Comment: Please pretend you don't know anything about your problem, and then read what you wrote. Does it make any sense to you? It doesn't to me. Perhaps if you show a small table with sample data and explain exactly what you are trying to do, it will help volunteers here understand what you need.

Comment: @Aleksej Thanks, forgot to type FROM statement. I'm trying to get all the columns that meet the value while only holding distinct values. Hopefully that makes sense.

Comment: Please try to explain your need with some sample data and desired result; without this, it's hard to understand what you expect from `DISTINCT column_name2 IS NOT NULL`

Comment: @Aleksej I've added an example table, hopefully that explains it better.

Comment: @mathguy I apologize, first time posting here. I've edited my post, hopefully it gives you a better idea now.

Comment: So, let's see if I understand... you want all the rows where GLASS_ID is in a set of input values. If two rows have different, non-null values in the INV_ID column, you want to retrieve both rows, even if they have the same GLASS_ID, because they have distinct INV_ID. But if they have the same GLASS_ID and the same INV_ID, you don't them selected at all. (Or you do want them, but only one, without a duplicate?) And, what do you mean you want to select all the columns - if two rows have the same GLASS_ID and same INV_ID, but different values in other columns, which row should be chosen?

Comment: @mathguy So basically I've been playing around and got what I pretty much needed replacing my AND statement using this AND statement...
AND INV_ID IN (SELECT max(INV_ID) FROM TABLE group by GLASS_ID)

It still gives me non-distinct INV_ID but it reduces the amount of rows returned to a much smaller amount, which I can adjust.

Sorry for not being clear about what exactly I was looking for, it's hard to explain without being able to divulge the example. I really appreciate you trying to help me, even though I know I wasn't very good at giving you a starting place.

Comment: No worries - we are here to help. Good to hear you found a solution to your problem!